# Array of viewChilds in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've this sample code that's works very nice...

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

 }

 ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.loadMap();
 }

loadMap(){

 let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);

 let mapOptions = {
  center: latLng,
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }

this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

}
}
```

This will basically display a map when it's locates the div bellow:

```
<div #map id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

But I've an array of maps in fact....So, the question is : how to archive an array of view-childs ?

I need something like...

```
for(let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  @ViewChild('map' + i) mapElement[i]: ElementRef;
}
```

and a function like "loadMaps()"

This is is much more an angular question rather than ionic2 in fact.

Comment: How about an array of Components instead?  1 component => 1 Map

Comment: @axlj this may not work, because we will have duplicated ids on the divs.

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ViewChildren y QueryList:

First import them:

```
import { ViewChildren,QueryList } from '@angular/core';
```

Use it into the class like ViewChild:

```
@ViewChildren("div") divs: QueryList<any>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewChildren` to query for a list of components.

More information here:

https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

You can query on a class name, so you could give all of your maps the same class name and query against that directly.

Answer (score 0):

multiple `#templateReference` variable is not allowed. So you can use `directive` instead. I'd suggest not to go with ViewChild or any other API like `ViewChildren` or `ContentChildren` or etc.

**NOTE:** This code is not tested but probably one of good approaches that you can go with.

```
import {MapDirective} from 'MapDirective relative path';


<div map id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div map id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div map id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

## MapDirective

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core;

@Directive({
  selector: '[map]'
})

export class MapDirective{
  constructor(ele:ElementRef){
    this.loadMap();
  }

  // please make sure that you import google-map library before using it
  loadMap(){

     let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);

     let mapOptions = {
         center: latLng,
         zoom: 15,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }

     new google.maps.Map(this.ele.nativeElement, mapOptions);
}
```